# MVC C# Retrieving selecteditem intoDropdownlist on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist in a view and a button. now when I click the button it loads data according to the value of the dropdownlist value. the filtering works and displays the page perfectly but the dropdownlist value keeps re-setting. I want it to retrieve the last selected value.

This is my view with page AllDates.cshtml and the button will filter and return same page again:

```
@{

ViewBag.Title = "All Cars";

}

<form name="filter" action="~/Home/AllDates" method="post" >
 <select id="fly" name='fly' >
 <option value='Any'>Any</option>
 <option value='plane'>plane</option>
 <option value='kyte'>kyte</option>
 </select>
 <input id="Refine" type="Submit" value="Refine" />
```

Here is my controller. Ive been told calling the controls using Request is not a good option but I am new to MVC and it seems to be difficult.

```
public ViewResult AllDates() {

                     Session["fly"] = Request["fly"];



          var  allDates = MyObjectToPreview;

          return View(allDates);
      }
```

This is working great but now how am I meant to get the Session["fly"] to be retrieved into the dropdown selected item once the view loads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you don't need to save this to `Session`. That's an unnecessary step that doesn't buy you anything. Second, you're defining your `select` manually, which means there's no opportunity here for Razor to do anything like setting the selected value. If you build the `select` manually, then you're also responsible for setting the selected value manually, for example:

```
<select id="fly" name="fly">
    <option value="Any" @(Request["fly"] == "Any" ? "selected" : string.Empty)>Any</option>
    ...
</select>
```

The better approach is to let Razor handle the select list for you:

```
@Html.DropDownList("fly", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem { Text = "Any", Value = "Any" },
    ...
})
```

Since Razor is involved in building the HTML, now, it can properly select the right option based on the value of `Request["fly"]`.

Comment: that's a great answer (the first option). how can you use that logic on a foreach loop? 

         "@foreach (var item in ViewData["SomeData"]
                    as List<Model> )
                        {         
                         <option> @item.options
                         </option>            
                        }"

Comment: Any answer for the above comment please> Also I would like to know if there's a similar method as the first option but for normal aspx  (which doesn't support "@" but <%%> instead. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use from ViewBag and access to ViewBag in View like :

```
public ViewResult AllDates() {
   ViewBag.FlyVal = Request["fly"];
...
}
```

and in view in document.ready use :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#fly").val('@ViewBag.FlyVal');

});
</script>
```

The other approach is use ajax request to add filter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AllDates(string filter) {
   ViewBag.FlyVal = Request["fly"];
...
return json();
}

//Client
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'Action URL',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: {filter : $("#fly").val()},
dataType: "json",
success: function(result) {
alert(result);        
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `viewdata` also:

```
public ActionResult Viewresult()
{
    ViewData["flyval"] = request["fly"];
    return View();
}
```

In view:

```
@ViewData["Flyval"]
```